# hibernate.cfg.xml does load on my project

Tags: java, hibernate

My hibernate.cfg.xml seems not been loaded when I start the webapp.

The file is in src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

I need some help please.

Thanks

edit hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/website</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">test</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.hsh.entity.User"/>
    <mapping class="com.hsh.entity.Address"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my hibernateUtils class file:

```
package com.website.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtils {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return sessionFactory;
  }

}
```

Here the error I have.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.hibernate.HibernateBaseDAO._all(HibernateBaseDAO.java:418)
    com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.hibernate.GenericDAOImpl.findAll(GenericDAOImpl.java:61)
    com.website.service.impl.AddressServiceImpl.getAllAddresss(AddressServiceImpl.java:16)
com.website.controller.AddressController.listAddress(AddressController.java:18)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)

org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Show us more. Your Hibernate util class and hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I just added these files in my post

Comment: what exceptions are you getting?

Comment: When I wrote some sh!t on my hibernate.xml file, I have no error. that's a it weird. Then the error that I have when I reach a page that use the bd (I use genericDAO from http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) is now added in the post.

Comment: By default Hibernate take its file from the root so not inside src/main/resources/

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the hibernate.cfg.xml? the stacktrace doesn't show anything about that... did you debug it to see what is null?

Comment: I just put the file in the root next to my pom.xml. Same result

Comment: I added more error from the stacktrace. @fmodos. Null seems to be the hibernate session

Comment: @fliim try to add it to the src folder, which should be compiled to the folder WEB-INF/classes when deployed, or add it manually to this folder for test

Comment: @fmodos the file is already in the WEB-INF/classes and I added it in the src folder. But still got the error

Comment: ok @fliim http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-the-type-annotationconfiguration-is-deprecated/ not sure what is your hibernate version, but change it to Configuration instead of AnnotationConfiguration in your HibernateUtils

Comment: @fmodos THis could be a solution to fix my issue but it doesn't work.

Comment: @fliim maybe it is been loaded and another internal problem is happening, try to debug it when session factory is created

Comment: @fmodos I dont think that the factory is created. I cant debug at the moment.